# Cannot display a message when string is not found -Java

Tags: java, loops, methods

I am working on an assignment in which the user can lookup U.S. presidents by either first or last name. That part works but I when I try to have it display a message if the name isn't found it either doesn't display or also displays when the name is found. I'm very new to java and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //calls method which checks that the file exists
    checkForDocument();

    // declares String name
    String name = null;

    //Sets button text to "Search by first name" for the first button and "Search by last name" for the second button
    Object[] options = {"Search by first name", "Search by last name"};

    //creates frame
    Component frame = null;

    // displays the following message above the options within the dialog box
    int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
            "Presidents of The United States ",

            //
            null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,

            //
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[1]);

    // if the user clicks search by first name
    if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

        //firstNameSearch method is called
        firstNameSearch();

        //if user clicks search by last name
    } else if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {

        //prompts the user to enter a name and assigns it to lastName
        String   lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a last name");

        //calls the LastNameSearch method
        lastNameSearch(lastName);

    } 


    // trailing else
    else 
    {
        //
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You must choose an option");

    }

}


//method for searching by first name
public static void firstNameSearch () throws IOException {

    File file = new File ("USPres.txt");

    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    //declares count
    int count;

    //user is prompted to enter a first name
    String firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a first name");

    for  ( count = 1; inputFile.hasNext(); ++count)
    {
        // assigns string line to inputFile's Next line
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();

        //assigns string firstWord to first word in line
        String firstWord = line.split(" ")[0];

        //if firstWord equals firstNem
        if (firstWord.compareToIgnoreCase(firstName)==0)
        { 
            //prints the line
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,line);
        } 

        if ( count > 44)

            if (firstWord.compareToIgnoreCase(firstName)!=0)

                JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null, "Name not found");
    }

}

//method for searching by last name
public static void lastNameSearch(String lastName) throws IOException

{   
    //checks that document exists
    checkForDocument();

    // declares String lastWord
    String lastWord = null;

    File   file = new File ("USPres.txt");

    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    // declares the string line
    String line = null;

    //while file has another line
    while(inputFile.hasNext()) {

        //assigns variable line to next line of input file
        line = inputFile.nextLine();   

        //assigns last word of a line to lastWord
        lastWord = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);


        //if lastWord is equal to  the last name input by the user
        if(lastWord.compareToIgnoreCase(lastName)==0) { 

            //prints the line
            JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null,line);

        }
    }
}

// Checks that file exists
public static void checkForDocument() throws IOException
{
    // checks that USPres.txt exists
    try
    {
        //assigns file to USPres.txt
        File   file = new File ("USPres.txt");

        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    }

    // deals with FileNotFoundException
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        //message which displays if file does not exist
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. File not found");

        //terminates program
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

//displayMessage method header
public static void displayMessage() throws IOException{

    //displays message
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name not found");

    //terminates program
    System.exit(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only say that a name could not found if you iterate through all names with the for/while loop. If a name has found you can take the result and break the loop with a return.
If every iteration of the loop was not successful, you can be sure the name could not found. You can also add conditions after the loop. For example for different dialog messages.

```
for (int i=0; i<maxCount && inputFile.hasNext(); i++) {
    ...
        
    if (firstWord.compareToIgnoreCase(firstName) == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line);
        return;
    }
}

displayMessage();
```

Hint for the next step: Try to extract duplicate code and use the methods with arguments. For example the file path. ;)